# p:inputMask how to detect event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to be able to detect an event when a user starts typing in a p:inputMask control - is there any example available on how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood `p:inputMask` is a Text Field with some script attached to it for masking.
So it supports all the events of a Text Field.
You can use `keyup` event for your purpose.
For Example:

```
<h:outputText value="Date: " />  
<p:inputMask value="#{myBean.maskDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" onstart="alert('Key Pressed')"/>
</p:inputMask>
```